# 英語が残っている:ヘルプ>弊社のモデル>What is beta mean?

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ

ヘルプに英語が残っています。[リンク](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-beta)
回答で投稿した物で様子見しOKだったら反映してもらおうと思います。

### What does "beta" mean?

This site was created through the [open democratic process](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) at [Stack Exchange Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). Sites created through this process begin in “beta”, which means that the site is still being defined and constructed. There are a few differences between beta and non-beta sites in our network:

- All beta sites have the same temporary placeholder design. Once the site is no longer beta, it will have a unique design built with input from the community.
- Reputation thresholds for [privileges](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/privileges) are lower during the beta phase to help ensure community governance early on.
- In early beta, the Stack Exchange team [appoints moderators](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) until the site is large enough to sustain a democratic [moderator election](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work).

During beta, the community works together to answer [seven essential questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) for every Stack Exchange site:

1. Are questions about {subject} on or off topic?
2. What should our FAQ contain?
3. How should we tag questions about {subject}?
4. Who should the moderators be?
5. What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?
6. What should our logo and site design look like?
7. How do we promote our site?

There is no set amount of time for a site to remain in beta; it will be in beta [for as long as necessary to reach critical mass](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/), with periodic evaluations that help communities know where they stand and what they need to work on.

Comment: 参考: [The Real Essential Questions of Every Beta - Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223674/286934)

Comment: [これ](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/2257/15185)で反映してもらうことにします。メールで反映をお願いしようと考えています。別の方法のほうが良いならコメントして頂けるとありがたいです。

Comment: それでもいいですが、誰かモデレーターに@してもらうか、翻訳支援ルームに書いてもらえれば伝えます。あとメタ投稿は時々見ているので、編集でageてもらうだけでも。

Comment: @unarist ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

翻訳案 Translation draft

---

#### ベータとは何ですか？

StackExchangeネットワークで生まれたサイトは、まだ定義や構築の途中という意味を込めて、ベータ版から始めることになります。ベータ版の間は他のサイトといくつか異なる点があります。

- ベータ版の間はサイトのデザインは共通です。ベータを卒業するときに、コミュニティの意見を取り入れながら専用のデザインが作られます。
- 早い段階からコミュニティによる自治が行えるように、[権限](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/privileges)の解放に必要な信用度は低めになっています。
- [モデレーター選挙](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)をするのに十分な規模になるまでは、Stack Exchangeチームが[臨時モデレーター](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work)を任命します。

そしてベータの間に、Stack Exchangeサイトのために用意された[7つの質問](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)の答えを考えます。

1. ○○に関する質問はオントピック、オフトピックどちらでしょうか？
2. サイトのFAQに何を記載すべきでしょうか？
3. どんな時に、どんなタグを使うべきでしょうか？
4. モデレーターは誰がいいでしょうか？
5. 私たちのサイトがどんなサイトなのかを簡潔に説明するとしたら？（エレベーターピッチ）
6. どのようなロゴやサイトデザインがいいでしょうか？
7. サイトをより多くの人に使ってもらうには？

ベータ版に固定の期間はありません。サイトが今どんな状況にあって何をしなければならないのかを定期的に確認しながら、[コミュニティが十分に成熟して](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/)ベータを卒業することを目指します。

Comment: 色々いじりました。ja.SOに関してはArea51を通していないので省略しました。クリティカルマスに関しては16%という数字に意味があるわけではないですし、[英語圏ほど（？）](http://sigmalanguage.jugem.jp/?eid=19)馴染みのある言葉でもないと思うので、別の言い回しを探る方がいいかと。

Comment: @unarist Thanks!